# Who is Wodibin (Warwick Davis' cameo) in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Warwick Davis [is credited as playing the character "Wodibin"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2527336/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) in The Last Jedi

Originally I had thought he was:

> The guy who mistook BB8 for a slot machine

But that turned out to be played by someone else.  So then, who is Wodibin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wodibin is a male Suerton

He resided in Canto Bight.

He was nicknamed Wodi in the *Journey to the Last Jedi: Canto Bight* Novella Collection. His brothers were Dodi and Thodi.

Wodi features prominently in the Novella Collection and is in Canto Bight when Kaljach Sonmi meets the Lucky Three.

The following image is taken from the Visual Dictionary

[image: Wodibi]